# The median minimizes the sum of absolute deviations (the $ {\ell}_{1} $ norm)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, absolute-value, median

> Suppose we have a set $S$ of real numbers. Show that
>   $$\sum_{s\in S}|s-x| $$
>   is minimal if $x$ is equal to the median.

This is a sample exam question of one of the exams that I need to take and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Please replace *THE median* by *ANY median*.

Comment: For completeness, [here](http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/10/04/expectation-median-opt/) is Gregory Gundersen's  nice explanation for the continuous case (when $S$ contains an *infinite* number of real numbers).

Comment: To clarify the comment by @Did above, where they say "ANY median" they mean "any point between the two middle elements", when there are an even number of elements in the set S. When S contains an odd number of elements, there is, of course, only one median.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85448/why-does-the-median-minimize-ex-c

Answer (score 142, accepted):

**Introduction:** The solution below is essentially the same as the solution given by Brian M. Scott, but it will take a lot longer. You are expected  to assume that $S$ is a finite set. with say $k$ elements. Line them up in order,  as $s_1<s_2<\cdots <s_k$.

The situation is a little different when $k$ is odd than when $k$ is even. In particular, if $k$ is even there are (depending on the exact definition of median) many medians. We tell the story first for $k$ odd.
Recall that $|x-s_i|$ is the **distance** between $x$ and $s_i$, so we are trying to minimize the sum of the distances. For example, we have $k$ people who live at various points on the $x$-axis. We want to find the point(s) $x$ such that the **sum** of the travel distances of the $k$ people to $x$ is a minimum.

**The story:** Imagine that the $s_i$ are points on the $x$-axis. For clarity, take $k=7$. Start from well to the left of all the $s_i$, and take a tiny step, say of length $\epsilon$, to the right. Then you have gotten $\epsilon$ closer to every one of the $s_i$, so the sum of the distances has decreased by $7\epsilon$.

Keep taking tiny steps to the right, each time getting a decrease of $7\epsilon$. This continues until you hit $s_1$. If you now take a tiny step to the right, then your distance from $s_1$  *increases* by $\epsilon$, and your distance from each of the remaining $s_i$  decreases by $\epsilon$. What has happened to the sum of the distances? There is a decrease of $6\epsilon$, and an increase of $\epsilon$, for a net decrease of $5\epsilon$ in the sum.

This continues until you hit $s_2$. Now, when you take a tiny step to the right, your distance from each of $s_1$ and $s_2$ increases by $\epsilon$, and your distance from each of the five others decreases by $\epsilon$, for a
net decrease of $3\epsilon$.

This continues until you hit $s_3$. The next tiny step gives an increase of $3\epsilon$, and a decrease of $4\epsilon$, for a net decrease of $\epsilon$.

This continues until you hit $s_4$. The next little step brings a total increase of $4\epsilon$, and a total decrease of $3\epsilon$, for an *increase* of $\epsilon$. Things get even worse when you travel further to the right. So the minimum sum of distances is reached at $s_4$, the median.

The situation is quite similar if $k$ is even, say $k=6$. As you travel to the right, there is a net decrease at every step, until you hit $s_3$. When you are between $s_3$ and $s_4$, a tiny step of $\epsilon$ increases your distance from each of $s_1$, $s_2$, and $s_3$ by $\epsilon$. But it decreases your distance from each of the three others, for no net gain. Thus any $x$ in the interval from  $s_3$ to $s_4$, including the endpoints, minimizes the sum of the distances. In the even case, I prefer to say that **any** point between the two "middle" points is **a** median. So the conclusion is that the points that minimize the sum are the medians. But some people prefer to define **the** median in the even case to be the average of the two "middle" points. Then the median does minimize the sum of the distances, but some other points also do.

Answer (score 115):

We're basically after:
$$ \arg \min_{x} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left| {s}_{i} - x \right| $$

One should notice that $ \frac{\mathrm{d} \left | x \right | }{\mathrm{d} x} = \operatorname{sign} \left( x \right) $ (Being more rigorous would say it is a Sub Gradient of the non smooth $ {L}_{1} $ Norm function).
Hence, deriving the sum above yields $ \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \operatorname{sign} \left( {s}_{i} - x \right) $.
This equals to zero only when the number of positive items equals the number of negative which happens when $ x = \operatorname{median} \left\{ {s}_{1}, {s}_{2}, \cdots, {s}_{N} \right\} $.

**Remarks**

1. One should notice that the `median` of a discrete group is not uniquely defined.
2. The median is not necessarily an item within the group.
3. Not every set can bring the Sub Gradient to vanish. Yet employing the Sub Gradient Method is guaranteed to converge to median.
4. It is not the optimal way to calculate the Median. It is given to give intuition about what's the median.

Comment: Using derivatives here is overkill; the problem can be done by more elementary methods. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy actually among all answers I find this one to be the simplest, rather than the "walk to the left and then to the right of the real line".

Comment: To the point. :)

Comment: The derivative of |x| is x/|x| as proven here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/finding-the-derivative-of-x-using-the-limit-definition

Comment: @clytondantis, The function $ \frac{x}{ \left| x \right| } $ is one of the definitions of $ \operatorname{sign} \left( \cdot \right) $.

Comment: How does this proof work when there are an even number of elements and $x$ has to be one of the elements? In this case, the dervative of the objective function set equal to zero cannot be solved, but there would either be more positive elements than negative, or vice versa.

Comment: e.g., consider [1,2,3,4]. If we choose the median to be 2, then the number of positive elements is 2 and the number of negative residuals is 1. So the sum of the signs is non-zero.

Comment: @David, In the case you raised the median isn't well defined in the set. Then you'll see both the above proof and mine define the solution to be $ \left( 2, 3 \right) $. Yet pay attention to the problem formulation, $ x $ is free to be median, only the $ s $ must be in the given set.

Comment: (2,3) means not inclusive of 2 and 3 right?

Comment: @David, Yes, indeed. But again, the problem, as defined above, doesn't enforce the solution to be one of the items in the set.

Comment: Right. I understand. I came across a similar problem, except the solution had to be constrained to one of the problems in the set. I tried to adapt your method to it, but I reach a contradiction when I set the derivative to zero. It either ends with 1 = 0 or -1 = 0.

Comment: @David, Open a question with your case and I will post a solution (Link it here).

Comment: Just opened. Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730510/extension-of-median-minimizing-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations-the-l-1-norm Thanks

Comment: How about $s_i \in \{1, 2, 3, 3, 4\}$ ?

Comment: @Kumar, What do you mean?

Comment: Its an example where the sum of the sub-gradients will not be zero.

Comment: You're asking the other side of the coin as @David asked. This is the objective function for your set https://i.imgur.com/vjwulkS.png. If you apply Sub Gradient descent using the defined above Sub Gradient it will converge to the Median of the set which is $ 3 $. So what's the problem?

Comment: Could you please explain how the median of a discrete set of numbers is not unique? For instance in set {1, 2, 3, 4} isn't the mean just 2.5? of can we set any number between 2 and 3 as median?

Comment: @Fatemeh_Asgarinejad, Indeed any number between 2 and 3 minimizes the cost function to the same value. The issue is the cost function being convex yet not strictly convex (Many solution with the same value).

Comment: thanks for your response @Royi! So, are we saying that any number that for which the cost function yields a similar value is median? So, I mean any float number between 2 and 3 is median. Is that right?

Comment: Float number is a term of a representation of number for computers. Any number (Real Number), Real Number in the range $ (2, 3) $ will yield the same objective value for the above. You could have tried calculating it by your self.

Comment: You can see that if there is an even number of terms, there is a minimum of the function $f(x)=\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left| {s}_{i} - x \right|$ , but the function is flat and the $\arg \min_{x} f(x)$ is an open interval , in the desmos example the $\arg \min_{x} f(x) $  is any $x$ in  $(4,8)$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8o3ufaklqu

Comment: @FatemehAsgarinejad The answer to your question will depend on how you define median. Many people intuitively take the average of the two middle values as the definition of THE median of an even amount of numbers. If you define it using the minimization of that cost function, there will be many medians.

Answer (score 51):

Suppose that the set $S$ has $n$ elements, $s_1<s_2<\dots<s_n$. If $x<s_1$, then $$f(x)=\sum_{s\in S}|s-x|=\sum_{s\in S}(s-x)=\sum_{k=1}^n(s_k-x)\;.\tag{1}$$ As $x$ increases, each term of $(1)$ decreases until $x$ reaches $s_1$, therefore $f(s_1)<f(x)$ for all $x<s_1$.

Now suppose that $s_k\le x\le x+d\le s_{k+1}$. Then

$$\begin{align*}f(x+d)&=\sum_{i=1}^k\Big(x+d-s_i\Big)+\sum_{i=k+1}^n\Big(s_i-(x+d)\Big)\\
&=dk+\sum_{i=1}^k(x-s_i)-d(n-k)+\sum_{i=k+1}^n(s_i-x)\\
&=d(2k-n)+\sum_{i=1}^k(x-s_i)+\sum_{i=k+1}^n(s_i-x)\\
&=d(2k-n)+f(x)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $f(x+d)-f(x)=d(2k-n)$. This is negative if $2k<n$, zero if $2k=n$, and positive if $2k>n$. Thus, on the interval $[s_k,s_{k+1}]$

$$f(x)\text{ is }\begin{cases}
\text{decreasing},&\text{if }2k<n\\
\text{constant},&\text{if }2k=n\\
\text{increasing},&\text{if }2k>n\;.
\end{cases}$$

From here it shouldn’t be too hard to show that $f(x)$ is minimal when $x$ is the median of $S$.

Comment: To me it looks simple, accurate and without hacks. Thank you!

Comment: I would change equation (1) to use i instead of k, because k has a different meaning later on. I would personally explain how to use the final result to reason that the median of an odd number of numbers is the middle number whereas, if median is defined by minimizing (1), there is a range of medians between the values of the two most center numbers (potentially a single value if both numbers are equal).

Comment: @user974006: The elements of the set $S$ are by definition distinct, so the two central numbers when $n=|S|$ is even are necessarily distinct, and the median of $S$ is the arithmetic mean of those two numbers. $f$ attains its minimum at every point of that interval, so in particular it is minimal at the median of $S$. I deliberately left the easy final step to the reader: for elementary problems it is my normal practice either to give a hint (whose magnitude depends on the question) or to leave a few details to the reader, since I want the OP to think about it a bit. \\ Since $k$ in $(1)$ ...

Comment: ... is clearly an index variable, while $k$ in the rest of the answer clearly is not, it should be clear its meaning changes after the first paragraph, and it should also be clear that there is no conflict. This question is at a level at which students should be able to deal with such things or at least be learning to do so.

Answer (score 17):

You want the median of $n$ numbers.  Say $x$ is bigger than $12$ of them and smaller than $8$ of them (so $n=20$).  If $x$ increases, it's getting closer to $8$ of the numbers and farther from $12$ of them, so the sum of the distances gets greater.  And if $x$ decreases, it's getting closer to $12$ of them and farther from $8$ of them, so the sum of the distances gets smaller.

A similar thing happens if $x$ is smaller than more of the $n$ numbers than $x$ is bigger than.

But if $x$ is smaller than $10$ of them and bigger than $10$ of them, then when $x$ moves, it's getting farther from $10$ of them and closer to just as many of them, so the sum of the distances is not changing.

So the sum of the distances is smallest when the number of data points less than $x$ is the same as the number of data points bigger than $x$.

Answer (score 12):

Consider two real numbers $a<b$. Then the objective becomes

$$dist(a,b) = |x-a|+|x-b|$$

This expression is minimum when $a\leq x \leq b$. It can be proved by calculating the objective on 3 cases ($x<a, a\leq x\leq b, x>b$).

Now consider the general case where $S$ has $n$ elements. Sort them in increasing order as $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n$.

Pair the smallest and the largest numbers. As explained above, $dist(S_1,S_n)$ is minimum when $S_1\leq x\leq S_n$. Remove these two elements from the list and continue this procedure until there is at most one element left in the set.

If there is an element $S_i$ left, then $x=S_i$ minimizes $dist(x-S_i)$. It also lies between all the pairs.

In the case of even elements, finally the sequence will be empty. As in the case above, median lies between all the pairs.

Answer (score 10):

Starting with $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n |s_i-x|$$

Assume we rearranged our terms such that $s_1<s_2<\cdots<s_n$

We first proceed by making the following observation $$\sum_{i=1}^n |s_i-x| = \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} |s_i-x| +(s_n -s_1) \quad \text{when} \quad x \in [s_1,s_n]$$

Now suppose that $n$ is odd, then by applying the above identity repeatedly we get $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n |s_i-x|=|s_{\frac{n+1}2}-x|+(s_n -s_1)+(s_{n-1}-s_2)+\cdots+(s_{\frac{n+3}2}-s_{\frac{n-1}2})$$ or in other words $$f(x)=|s_{\frac{n+1}{2}}-x|+\text{constant}$$

This is just the absolute value function with its vertex being at $(s_{\frac{n+1}{2}},\text{constant})$, the minimum of the absolute value function occurs at its vertex, therefore $s_{\frac{n+1}{2}}$(median) minmizes $f(x)$.

Now suppose $n$ is even, again by using our identity, we have $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n |s_i-x|=|s_{\frac{n}2}-x|+|s_{\frac{n+2}2}-x| + \text{constant}$$

Where the minimum occurs at $f'(x)=0$(or when not defined), therefore by differentiating and setting $f'(x)$ to zero we get $$\dfrac{|s_{\frac{n}{2}}-x|}{s_{\frac{n}{2}}-x}+\dfrac{|s_{\frac{n+2}{2}}-x|}{s_{\frac{n+2}{2}}-x}=0$$

Observe that $s:=\dfrac{s_{\frac{n+2}{2}}+s_{\frac{n}{2}}}{2}$(median) satisfies the above equation, since $s$ is halfway between $s_{\frac{n}{2}}$ and $s_{\frac{n+2}{2}}$ $$s_{\frac{n}{2}}-s=-(s_{\frac{n+2}{2}}-s)$$ that is by setting $x=s$ we get $$\dfrac{|s_{\frac{n}{2}}-s|}{s_{\frac{n}{2}}-s}+\dfrac{|s_{\frac{n}{2}}-s|}{-(s_{\frac{n}{2}}-s)}=0$$

Therefore $s$ is a minimum.

Comment: I think some theory about minimum being where $f'(x) = 0$ for non differentiable functions is needed here

Answer (score 5):

Consider two $x_i$'s $x_1$ and $x_2$,

For $x_1\leq a\leq x_2$, $\sum_{i=1}^{2}|x_i-a|=|x_1-a|+|x_2-a|=a-x_1+x_2-a=x_2-x_1$

For $a\lt x_1$, $\sum_{i=1}^{2}|x_i-a|=x_1-a+x_2-a=x_1+x_2-2a\gt x_1+x_2-2x_1=x_2-x_1$

For $a\gt x_2$,$\sum_{i=1}^{2}|x_i-a|=-x_1+a-x_2+a=-x_1-x_2+2a\gt -x_1-x_2+2x_2=x_2-x_1$

$\implies$for any two $x_i$'s the sum of the absolute values of the deviations is minimum when $x_1\leq a\leq x_2$ or $a\in[x_1,x_2]$.

**When $n$ is odd,**
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a|=|x_1-a|+|x_2-a|+\cdots+\left|x_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}}-a\right| + \left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a\right|+\left|x_{\tfrac{n+3}{2}}-a|+\cdots+|x_{n-1}-a\right|+|x_n-a|
$$
consider the intervals $[x_1,x_n], [x_2,x_{n-1}], [x_3,x_{n-2}], \ldots, \left[x_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}}, x_{\tfrac{n+3}{2}}\right]$. If $a$ is a member of all these intervals. i.e, $\left[x_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n+3}{2}}\right],$

using the above theorem, we can say that all the terms in the sum except $\left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a\right|$ are minimized. So
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a|=(x_n-x_1)+(x_{n-1}-x_2)+(x_{n-2}-x_3)+\cdots + \left(x_{\tfrac{n+3}{2}}-x_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}}\right) + \left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a\right| = \left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a \right|+\text{costant}
$$
Now since the derivative of modulus function is signum function, $f'(a)=\operatorname{sgn}\left(x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a\right)=0$ for $a=x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}=\text{Median}$

$\implies$ When $n$ is odd,the median minimizes the sum of absolute values of the deviations.

**When $n$ is even,**
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a|=|x_1-a|+|x_2-a|+\cdots+|x_{\tfrac{n}{2}}-a|+|x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}-a|+\cdots+|x_{n-1}-a|+|x_n-a|\\
$$
If $a$ is a member of all the intervals $[x_1,x_n], [x_2,x_{n-1}], [x_3,x_{n-2}], \ldots, \left[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}\right]$, i.e, $a\in\left[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}\right]$,

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a|=(x_n-x_1)+(x_{n-1}-x_2)+(x_{n-2}-x_3)+\cdots + \left(x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}-x_{\tfrac{n}{2}}\right)
$$

$\implies$ When $n$ is even, any number in the interval $[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}]$, i.e, including the median, minimizes the sum of absolute values of the deviations. For example consider the series:$2, 4, 5, 10$, median, $M=4.5$.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^4|x_i-M|=2.5+0.5+0.5+5.5=9
$$
If you take any other value in the interval $\left[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2} + 1} \right] =[4,5]$, say $4.1$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^4|x_i-4.1|=2.1+0.1+0.9+5.9=9
$$
For any value outside the interval $\left[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}\right]=[4,5]$, say $5.2$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^4|x_i-5.2|=3.2+1.2+0.2+4.8=9.4
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $S=\{X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n\}$, w.l.o.g. assume $X_1\leq X_2 \leq \ldots \leq X_n$

$\implies D=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|X_k-x|=|X_1-x|+|X_2-x|+\ldots +|X_{n-1}-x|+|X_n-x|$

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{odd}^{+}$, i.e., $n=2m+1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, for $m=0$ it's trivial.

Also, let's notice that $D=|X_{m+1}-x|+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\left(|X_k-x| + |X_{n-k+1}-x|\right)$

Now, let's consider the sum $D_1=|X_1-x|+|X_n-x|$ and consider the following cases:

$(1) \quad x \leq X_1 \implies D_1=X_1+X_n-2x \geq X_n-X_1$

$(2) \quad x \geq X_n \implies D_1=2x-X_1-X_n \geq X_n-X_1$

$(3) \quad X_1 \leq x \leq X_n \implies D_1=X_n-X_1$

$\implies D_1$ is minimum when $X_1\leq x \leq X_n$

Similarly, $D_2=|X_2-x|+|X_{n-1}-x|$ is minimum when $X_2 \leq x \leq X_{n-1}$

$\ldots$

Likewise, $D_m=|X_m-x|+|X_{m+2}-x|$ is minimum when $X_m \leq x \leq X_{m+2}$

Finally, $D_{m+1}=|X_{m+1}-x|$ is minimum when $x=X_{m+1}$

Hence, $D$ is minimum when $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m+1}D_i$ is minimum, when each $D_i$ has minimum possible value for $i=1,2,\ldots m+1$

$\implies x=X_{m+1}$, i.e., at the median value $D$ is minimum.

Similarly, we can show the same result for $n \in \mathbb{Z_{even}^{+}}$ too.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S$ is finite (with cardinal $s$), without repetitions, and ordered. Then the sum of absolute values is continuous (sum of continuous functions), and piecewise linear (hence differentiable), with left-most slope $-s$. By induction, the slope increases by 2 for each interval from left to right, with right-most slope $+s$. Hence the piece-wise slope first reaches either  $-1$ or $0$ at index $\left\lfloor \frac{s+1}{2}\right\rfloor$, and  $0$ or $+1$ at index $\left\lceil \frac{s+1}{2}\right\rceil$.

Hence the function attains its minima in the interval $\left[\left\lfloor \frac{s+1}{2}\right\rfloor, \left\lceil \frac{s+1}{2}\right\rceil\right]$, which reduces to a singleton when $s$ is odd.

The notion of median for continuous functions is detailed in Sunny Garlang Noah, [The Median of a Continuous Function](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1209398394), Real Anal. Exchange, 2007

Answer (score 0):

As a start, i will define the median of a set with an even cardinality to be one of the two elements in the mid, for example {1,2,3,4} the median is either 2 or 3. and for a set with odd cardinality the median is the middle element.

Suppose that the set  has  elements,  and 1<2<⋯<, we will start by showing that the median gets min sum for sets of cardinality (size) 1,2, and that any problem can be reduced to a set of cardinality 1 or 2.

For set {}, the median is , and the sum is zero.
For set {1,2}, the median is either 1,2, and the sum is |1 - 2| always.
Obvioulsy its easy to see and prove for sets of sizes 1,2 or any other size, that if x is not one of the set elements then the sum bigger than than if x was an element in the set.

So we have proved that the median works for sets of sizes 1,2. Now lets consider set of size 3 where its sorted: {1,2,3}, to get the minimum its easy to see and prove, that we have to pick x such that x is between s1,s3. but for such an x, |s1 - x| + |s3 - x| is always the same and equals |1 - 3| and so x that acheives min for set {1,2,3} is the same for set {s1} which is s1, which is the median.

Its also not hard to show that the same logic applies for set of four elements, the element that achieves min for set of 4 elements is the same element that achieves min for a set of 2 elements which is the median. And using the same logic reduce the problem from a set of 7 elements to set of 5 elements, and from a set of 6 elements to a set of 4 elements,and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To find the minimum of

$$f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left| {s}_{i} - x \right|$$

we can just follow the usual road and demand $f'(x) \overset{!}{=} 0$ . So let's calculate the derivative
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \frac{{s}_{i} - x}{\left| {s}_{i} - x \right|} = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \text{sgn}( {s}_{i} - x )
$$
The sign-function can be expressed using [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) as $\text{sgn}(x) = [x > 0] - [x < 0]$ so we get<sup>1</sup>
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} [{s}_{i} > x] - \sum_{i = 1}^{N} [{s}_{i} < x] \overset{!}{=} 0
$$
Iverson brackets evaluate to 1 if the statement is true and zero otherwise. So one can already see here that the derivative can only be zero if the same number of true statements exists for each sum. This means the number of $s_i$ smaller than $x$ must be the same as the number of $s_i$ bigger than $x$.

To make this even more explizit write out the sums assuming the $s_i$ are realisations of a set/random variable $S$ for an arbitrary distribution
$$
f'(x) = (1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + \ldots)  - (0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + \ldots) = 0
$$
If the divide these sums by their length $N$
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{N}(1 + 1 +0 + 1 + \ldots )  - \frac{1}{N}(0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + \ldots) = 0
$$
we see that each (normalized) sum gives the probability for $s_i > x$ and  $s_i < x$. So we can rewrite the statement in terms of cumulative probability distributions like
$$
f'(x) = P(S > x) - P(S < x) = 0
$$
In addition we know from the conversation of probability that
$$
P(S > x) + P(S < x) = 1
$$
Combining both statements gives
$$
P(S < x) = P(S > x) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
But this is precisely the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Probability_distributions) of $x$ being the median of the distribution of the set $S$.

---

<sub>**Footnotes**</sub>

<sub>1. https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2021/06/08/average-and-median-via-optimization/</sub>