# minimize absolute value

Tags: algorithms, optimization

Suppose we have $n$ real numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. We know that the solution which minimizes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |x-a_i|
$$
is $x^*=$ median of $a_1, a_2\ldots, a_n$.

Now suppose that we should choose $k<n$ numbers, namely $x^*_1, x^*_2, \ldots, x^*_k$ which corresponds to the $a_i$'s. For example $x^*_1$ corresponds to $a_1$ and $a_2$; $x^*_2$ corresponds to $a_3$, $a_4$ and $a_5$ etc. which minimizes
$$ 
|x^*_1-a_1| + |x^*_1-a_2| + |x^*_2-a_3|+ x^*_2-a_4|+ |x^*_2-a_5|+  \ldots + |x^*_k-a_n|
$$

Let me give a more concrete example:

Suppose we have 2,4,5,11,14 and $k=2$. Thus we need to choose $x_1$ and $x_2$. If we choose $x_1=5$ and associate it to 2,4 and 5;  $x_2=11$ and associate it to 11 and 14 we get
$$
|2-5|+|4-5|+|5-5|+|11-11|+|14-11|=3+1+3=7
$$

The question is how we can choose such $x_k$'s and how we should associate them to $a_i$'s. Is there any algorithm?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for algorithms for [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). Does the standard algorithm section in above wiki page help?

Comment: @achillehui: Thanks, that is what I have been looking for.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270

Answer (score 1):

If you break your sum into multiple sums, one for each $x_k$, you see that each $x_k$ affects only one sum, and each sum depends on only $x_k$.  Therefore, to minimize the overall total, you minimize each individual sum.  Therefore, $x_k$ should be the median of the $a_i$ corresponding to it.

Comment: How can I choose the $a_i$ corresponding to $x_k$?

Comment: You said in the problem that you had $X_k$ corresponding to certain $a_i$'s.  If it isn't just given as part of the problem, then I do not understand the problem set up.