# Does the arithmetic mean minimize the sum of absolute values of deviations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, optimization

We have $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. I conjecture there to be a number $M \in  \mathbb{R}$ such that  for any $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ the quantity
$$|x_i - M|$$
is as small as possible. How do you go about proving that $M$ is the arithmetic mean
$$M=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i }{n}\text{ ?}$$

Comment: Do you want every *term* as small as possible, or the overall sum?

Comment: @pjs36 I have edited the question.

Comment: It doesn't look edited to me!

Comment: This conjecture is false. Take $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 10$. Then consider $M = 1, M = 5$. For $i = 1$, we get $|x_1 - 1| < |x_1 - 5|$. But for $i = 2$ we get $|x_2 - 1| > |x_2-5|$.

Comment: If you are trying to minimize the sum of those absolute values, $M$ is not the arithmetic mean, it is the *median*. For example, look at $x_1=1,\ x_2=2,\ x_3=9$. The mean $4$ gives you a sum of $11$, while the median $2$ gives a sum of only $9$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $M$ is real by assumption...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say each $|x_i-M|$ is as small as possible. These can be as small as $0$, while some other quantities may not be smallest possible. What do you mean exactly by *these* are as small as possible? If you meant sum of those to be smallest, then $M$ need not be unique: consider $x_0=0, x_1=1$ then any $M\in [0,1]$ minimises the sum.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270

Answer (score 6):

The value of $M$ that makes $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-M|$ as small as possible for given $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is the median, not the mean, of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

The value of $M$ that makes $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-M)^2$ as small as possible for given $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is the mean, not the median, of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

The first proposition can be proved as follows: If $M$ is bigger than more $x$ values than it's smaller than, then making $M$ smaller increases its distance from a few $x$ values and decreases its distance from many $x$ values, all by the same amount, so the sum of the distances gets smaller.  Then do the same with $M$ smaller than the median.

The second proposition can be shown as follows:
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-M)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n ((x_i -\text{mean})+(\text{mean}-M))^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\text{mean})^2 + \underbrace{2\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\text{mean})(\text{mean}-M)}_{\text{This sum is $0$.}} + \sum_{i=1}^n (\text{mean}-M)^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\text{mean})^2\right) + n(\text{mean}-M)^2.
\end{align}
To find the value of $M$ that makes this as small as possible, notice that $M$ appears only in the last term, so pick $M$ so as to make *that* as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

One other way to make sense of the Question is that we'd like to make the *largest* of the deviations $|x_i - M|$ as small as possible, i.e. find the real number $M$ that minimizes:

$$ \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} |x_i - M| $$

For this it suffices to choose $M$ to be the average of the largest and smallest values $x_i$.  Then the $\max |x_i - M|$ is half the (absolute) difference between those largest and smallest values.