# Linear programming: minimizing absolute values and formulate in LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, linearization

> Look for $x$ that minimizes $$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N| x – a_i |$$  with numbers $a_1, \dots, a_N$ that are given and formulate this as a linear program.

---

I have searched online and found that first of all this $\sum_i| x – a_i|$ should be made linear. The book that I have (aimms optimization modeling) didn't really intuitively help me to grasp how this can be done.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113270/339790)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple example to get you started:

$\min | x-3 | $

subject to

$x \leq 2$.

The key to formulating these problems is introducing auxilliary variables 
and additional constraints.  Add the constraints

$t \geq (x-3)$

and

$t \geq -(x-3)$.

Since $|x-3|$ is either $+(x-3)$ or $-(x-3)$, these constraints ensure that

$t \geq | x-3|$.

Now, minimize $t$.  This will ensure that $t$ is no bigger than $|x-3|$.
So, our problem is

$\min t$

subject to

$t \geq (x-3)$

$t \geq -(x-3)$

$x \leq 2$.

It's important to understand that this technique doesn't work to maximize
$|x-3|$.

You can easily extend this to more than one absolute value term, but you'll need an additional variable for each term.

Comment: You'd need a variable $t_{i}$ for each of the absolute value terms, with two inequalities ($t_{i} \geq (x-a_{i})$ and $t_{i} \geq -(x-a_{i})$, and the objective would be $\sum_{i} t_{i}$.

Comment: Many modeling systems can handle this problem transformation and others automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The objective with absolute value, can be written as follows

objective: $\min |x-3|$

$\Leftrightarrow$ objective:$\min \max(x-3,3-x)$

The linear programming with $\min \max(x-3,3-x)$ or $\max\min$ can be easily done. For example,

min $z$,

s.t. $t\geq x-3,$

$t\geq3-x$,

BTW, we provide another technique to solve the problem $\max \max (x-3,3-x)$.
Introduce a big value M and auxiliary variable b1,b2.

$\max t$,

s.t. $t\leq x-3+M*b_1,$

$t\leq3-x+M*b_2$,

$b_1+b_2=1.$

$b_1,b_2\in Z$

Comment: Here , I learn it from this question. [Using min/max *within* an Integer Linear Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792139/using-min-max-within-an-integer-linear-program)