# Find a number having minimum sum of distances between a set of numbers

Tags: optimization, average, median

Lets say we have a set of numbers $\{ 5, 7, 1, 2, 5, 100 \}$. I want to find a number $x$ such that the sum of distances of every number from the set to $x$ is minimal.

My first thought was that $x$ is the average of all elements of the set: $\frac{5+7+1+2+5+100}{6}$, but it is not true, it fails the above example.

Any help or hint will be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: The answer is wrong. For example, $100$ is closer to each element than $104$ is.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations-the-l-1-norm

Comment: @Harnak Sorry but I don't quite understand your statement. $104$ is the total distance $\sum_{x \in S} |x - n|$ where $n$ is the desired number and $S = \{1, 2, 5, 5, 7, 100\}$. How do you achieve $100$? See my proof.

Comment: @L.F., I was just answering to the OP before editing. He stated that the solution was 104, but I thought he referred to the minimizer and not to the distance. So, that's why I provided an example of why 104 couldn't be a minimizer. I think I just misinterpreted what he meant.

Comment: @Harnak Oh, never mind. Everybody makes mistakes :)

Comment: Setting $x=$ the "average"  (="the mean") minimizes the sqrt of sum-of-squares of the distances of each value from $x$. (This should also be in wikipedia at keyword "variance" and/or "arithmetic mean")

Comment: Anyone familiar with calculus can view this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1024462/1069875

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking to minimize $$\sum_{y \in A} |y - x|$$
with respect to $x$ where $A$ is your set.

It can be proved that  *any* median minimizes this problem. In your case, the only median is $5$, so that's the result.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's correct, but I'd like to make a suggestion about the phrase "this is a well known result": it appears to serve the purpose of making you look well-read, and the OP look ignorant, which might both be true, but does saying it help? Probably not. If you'd included a reference, that'd be great -- OP could learn something. Most likely, this exercise is *leading up* to the very result you cited, and explaining the computation in this case would be more educational than citing the very thing that can be proved in general from similar computations.

Comment: You're right. However, that was not my intent. I'll edit this. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 5):

First sort your [multi]set: $\{1, 2, 5, 5, 7, 100\}$. The number you want is $5$. The sum is $4 + 3 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 95 = 104.$

Proof: suppose you have another number $n \neq 5$.

Note that for any number $x$, $|x - a| + |x - b| \ge |a - b|$ by the triangle inequality, where equality holds if and only if $x$ is between $a$ and $b$ (inclusive).
Hence, it must hold that the sum of its distances to the two $5$s, i.e. $$|n - 5| + |n - 5| \ge |5 - 5| + |5 - 5| = 0.$$ Similarly, $$|n - 2| + |n - 7| \ge |5 - 2| + |5 - 7| = 5,$$
$$|n - 1| + |n - 100| \ge |5 - 1| + |5 - 100| = 99.$$

You can't have the total distance any lower.
Q.E.D.

In general, first sort your set, then any number between (including) the middle two numbers will do. For example, for set ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}$, any $x$ such that $3 \le x \le 4$ does.

Comment: Hi, any proof for |−|+|−|≤|−|? It seems to fail for x<=0 and a>0 & b>0. Example: x = 0, a = 2, and b = 4.

Comment: @Aryan it should be $\ge$.  I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks, it is much better now.