# How to show that the $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|A[i]-x|$ is minimal for $x=m$ with median $m$?

Tags: analysis, optimization, summation, normed-spaces, median

I am trying to solve this question, but have no idea how one can prove it:

> Let $m$ be the median of the array $A$ with $n$ real numbers. Show that
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\bigg|A[i]-x\bigg|$$
>
> is minimal for $x = m$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please first see the topic [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Questions lacking context or showing no effort from the OP will be closed and deleted. I think your question is asking for optimization in the $\mathcal{L}^1$ norm instead of $\mathcal{L}^2$. What have you tried so far? Look at how median is defined. That gives you a reordering of the terms in your sum. Since reordering terms doesn't change the outcome of the sum, you can assume that $A[i] \leq A[i+1]$ for all $i$. What can you do now?

Comment: Have a look at - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1024462/33.