# How to minimize $\| c \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\|_1$ without using linear programming?

Tags: optimization, vectors, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, linear-programming

Is there a closed form solution to the minimization problem
$$\min_{c \in \mathbb{R}}\left\lVert c \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\right\rVert_1$$
where $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & \dots & n \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a fixed vector, and the norm is the $1$-norm?

I know that this can be expressed as the linear program
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & \text{minimize } & & \boldsymbol{1}^T\mathbf{t} \\
   & \text{subject to } & &\begin{aligned}[t] -\mathbf{t} \leq c\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \leq \mathbf{t} \\
                \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}
but I'm wondering if there are other ways to solve this? Or do there exist any approximations that don't require solving a linear program? Thanks.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113270/339790).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}\|cx-y\|_1&= |y_0|+\sum_{i=1}^n|ci-y_i|\\
&=|y_0|+ \sum_{i=1}^n i|c-\frac{y_i}i|\end{align}

Note that $|y_0|$ doesn't have an influence on the choice of $c$.

Let $v$ be the sorted vector that consist of $i$ copies of $\frac{y_i}{i}$ (possibly with duplicity), where $1 \le i \le n$. Then $c$ can be chosen to be the median of the vector $v$.

Comment: oops, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Do you see any hope of handling the general case where $\bf x$ is neither a vector of ones nor a "ramp"?

Comment: no idea for that. I would like to see a cool approach for that too. :)

Comment: Posted a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3177147/339790).