# Extension of median minimizing the sum of absolute deviations (the $L_1$ norm)

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, lagrange-multiplier, median

This is an extension of the question asked in [The Median Minimizes the Sum of Absolute Deviations (The $ {L}_{1} $ Norm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations-the-l-1-norm/1024462?noredirect=1#comment7669180_1024462)
. Except with the extra constraint that $x \in S$.

The solutions provided there doesn't seem to work when the cardinality of the set is even (if it is odd, the solution is the median again). I'm particularly interested in the optimization approach (the one in Royi's answer).

With the above constraint, we now have a constraint optimization problem rather than an unconstrained problem:

$$
\arg \min_x \sum_{i=1}^n |s_i - x| \\
\text{subject to:  } x \in S
$$

I'm pretty certain that the solution to this problem, when the size of the set is even, is that $x$ can either be the $floor(n/2)$-th or $ceiling(n/2)$-th element of the SORTED set, where $n$ is the size of the size. For example, say $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$, so $n=8$. I believe $x$ can be 4 or 5 in this case.

Using Royi's approach, I am not sure how to account for the constraint. Would lagrange multipliers work for a constraint like $x \in S$?

Comment: Are we talking about scalars? Namely, $ {s}_{i} \in \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: @Royi Yes, scalars.

Answer (score 1):

The item which minimizes the function is called the [Medoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medoid) with respect to the distance by the absolute deviation in your case.

For scalars (Namely the case $ {s}_{i} \in \mathbb{R} $) the solution can be found in `O(n)` by the [Quick Select Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

In order to achieve a formal solution I'd go these steps:

1. The Objective Function Is Convex
   The objective function is a convex function hence there is a unique minimum value (Not argument).
2. The Objective Function Is Symmetric
   The objective function is symmetric around its minimizer(s).
   Namely being away from the minimizer by `s > t` means the value for `t` is better.

Integrating (1) and (2) means that we can use the solution with no constraints (Median) and the find the closest one to it. On a sorted list it becomes obvious.

Comment: Right, I would find it using Quick Select (this question was inspired by a programming competition problem). I couldn't tell from the wiki link, but is the medoid the median of an odd-sized array, and either of the middle elements in an even-sized array?

Comment: @David, The edge case you need to pay attention to is when there are copies of some element(s). Then you can have the edge case even in odd number of elements. If you talk about the unique elements then your observation is correct.