# Differentiability of "positive part" function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives

Let the positive part function be defined as $\max(0,x)$; this function is obviously not differentiable in $x=0$.

But what about the (more smooth) function $\big( \max(0,x) \big)^{2}$. I suspect the latter isn't differentiable in $x=0$ either, but it's not very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\max(0,x)={1\over 2}(x+|x|)$$
$$(\max(0,x))^2={1\over 4}(2x^2+2x|x|)$$
and this function is $C^1$ but not $C^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would provide a more detailed answer piggybacking off of Martin-Bias Perez Punilla's answer:

Indeed, we have that
$$\begin{align}
f_1(x) &:= \max(0,x) = \frac{x + |x|}{2} \\
f_2(x) &:= (\max(0,x))^2 = \frac{x^2 + x|x|}{2}.
\end{align}$$
Then, using the fact that $\frac{d|x|}{dx} = \frac{|x|}{x}$ via [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/finding-the-derivative-of-x-using-the-limit-definition), we have that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{df_1(x)}{dx} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{|x|}{x}\right), \\
\frac{df_2(x)}{dx} &= x + |x| = 2f_1(x), \\
\frac{df_2^2(x)}{dx} &= 1 + \frac{|x|}{x} = 2f_1'(x).
\end{align}
$$